# mktime() returning a huge amount of seconds

Tags: c, unix, mktime

In a simple test getting the elapsed time in seconds since de Unix Epoch (01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC) to 22 of February of 2019, it has returned a huge number of **18446744072104596016**

Why not just **1550793600** seconds?

Isn't the `time_t` value portable?

---

The `tm struct` printed out in gdb console had the following values just before calling `mktime()`:

```
(gdb) p ltm
$4 = {tm_sec = 0, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 0, tm_mday = 22, tm_mon = 1, tm_year = 19, tm_wday = 0, tm_yday = 0, tm_isdst = 0}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining and printing the `time_t` value?

Comment: Post the actual code that shows `mktime()` returning such a huge value.

Comment: `tm_year = 19` that's year 1919, it's returning a big negative number.

Comment: @KamilCuk you nailed it! That answers everything! This year came outside from an argument, I didn't realize that it was outside of the desired range.

Comment: @KamilCuk *tm_year = 19 that's year 1919, it's returning a big negative number.*  Indeed.  Took me a while to confirm that the Unix date for Feb 22, 1919 is actually `18446744072104596016` if a 64-bit `time_t` is viewed as an unsigned value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
tm_year = 19
```

you are incorrectly using `mktime()` if you are expecting that input to represent the year 2019.

Per [**7.27.1 Components of time**, paragraph 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p4) of the C standard:

> The tm structure shall contain at least the following members, in any
>   order. The semantics of the members and their normal ranges are
>   expressed in the comments.
>
> ```
>      int    tm_sec;           //   seconds after the minute -- [0, 60]
>      int    tm_min;           //   minutes after the hour -- [0, 59]
>      int    tm_hour;          //   hours since midnight -- [0, 23]
>      int    tm_mday;          //   day of the month -- [1, 31]
>      int    tm_mon;           //   months since January -- [0, 11]
>      int    tm_year;          //   years since 1900
>      int    tm_wday;          //   days since Sunday -- [0, 6]
>      int    tm_yday;          //   days since January 1 -- [0, 365]
>      int    tm_isdst;         //   Daylight Saving Time flag
> ```

Note that the `tm_year` value is **denoted in years since 1900**.

You are likely getting the `time_t` value for Feb 22, 1919, which is -1604966400, or 18446744072104596016 unsigned.

Comment: I also have too much second but the reason is that high bytes are 0x49FB. why?

tm  tm;

strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);

type_t respDate = mktime(&tm); // type_t is long long

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "xxx %s, %d, 0x%llX, %lld", date, tm.tm_year, respDate >> 32, respDate & 0xFFFFFFFF);

//I (15448) app: xxx Thu, 04 Nov 2021 15:52:34 GMT, 121, 0x49FB, 1636041154

Answer (score 1):

In binary 18446744072104596016 is 1111111111111111111111111111111110100000010101100101001000110000 having 64 bits

probably are you using the negative value -1604955598 as an unsigned one